# Running my GIS application using dev-c++ gives "gdal201.dll is missing"

Tags: c++, gdal, dev-c++

I'm working on a GIS application in C++ using Dev-C++, and to start for now I'm using the code given in the tutorial in [Link](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)

I got it to compile without errors or warnings, but when I try to run it I get the error "The program can't start because gdal201.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."
I was looking at another question with the similar problem and tried to search this dll on internet, but couldn't find it anywhere, and somebody mentioned to ignore the error, but I don't know how to do that.

Can anybody help me on what to do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this question related to the IDE you're using?

Comment: I'm relatively new to some aspects of C programming, and have been seeing that some people have issues with one IDE or another while using this library, so I'm just specifying. But it seems it doesn't have to do with the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the DLL file(s) to be present either in the same directory as the executable, or in your `Path` variable for the system to be able to find them.  I personally prefer setting `Path`.  You might consider either adding `GDAL_DIR\bin` to your permanent `Path` by editing system or user environment variables, or else create a small batch file on the desktop which adds the directory to `Path` then starts `devenv.exe` if you need to manage several incompatible development environments for different projects.

(This has several advantages in my experience over copying the DLL files to the same directory as the executable: It's easier to manage dependencies by including all the necessary directories, as opposed to manually tracking down all the recursive dependencies.  It's also easier to manage updates of the DLLs if you can just update the GDAL installation directory, or update `Path` or the batch file to a newer GDAL installation directory, rather than having to track down all the places you've copied the DLLs to or having to manage post-build scripts to copy the DLLs every time.)

(Of course, when it comes time to create a self-contained installer, it's going to be easiest to copy the dependent DLLs to the installer image directory before building the installer.  Then something like CMake's `BundleUtilities` module can help in tracking down what DLLs need to be included.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I copy private DLLs to the output folder of the project, i.e. the same folder as the executable. For a commercial application, you may want to install the DLL, let the OS handle the management of it and use the Assemblies Manifest to help the loader find it.